# C++ Array function not returning correct result

Tags: c++, arrays, max

I am writing a function to return the maximum value of an array and currently it is not returning the right value.

Function:

```
int findMax(int maximum[ARRAY_SIZE])
{   
    int largest=maximum[0];

     for(int i=0;i<ARRAY_SIZE;i++)
    {
        if (maximum[i]>largest)
        {
          return largest=maximum[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Main function part:

```
cout<<"Maximum number: "<< findMax(numbers) <<endl;
```

Comment: You shouldn't return the value from within the loop but just save it. Return `largest` at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(int i=0;i<ARRAY_SIZE;i++)
{
    if (maximum[i]>largest)
    {
          return largest=maximum[i];
    }
}
```

The loop statement will stop when a larger value is found, it may not check all elements in array.
**It should be modified like below:**

```
for(int i=0;i<ARRAY_SIZE;i++)
    {
        if (maximum[i]>largest)
        {
          largest=maximum[i];
        }
    }
return largest;
```

Everytime you check an element in array, if it's larger than the current max value, then update max value to current element. Finally return the max value

Answer (score 2):

`return largest=maximum[i];` this line will make your loop return early by returning the first element found.

Probably you wanted to do just `largest = maximum[i];` and then `return largest;` after your loop.

But you are using C++, why do you need to roll your own `findMax` function:

```
int array[] = {1,100,65,21,12,5};
int* max = ::max_element(begin(array), end(array));
```

Answer (score 1):

`return` (sort of) immediately ends the function call. What you want is to update `largest` and, at the end of `findMax`, `return largest`.

You may also want to read a complete C++ course and name your parameters in a more logical way.

```
int findMax(int data[], std::size_t size)
{   
    int largest=data[0];

    for(std::size_t i=0 ; i < size ; ++i)
    {
        if (data[i] > largest)
        {
            largest = data[i];
        }
    }

    return largest;
}
```